# Laravel save when update not working (strange behavior)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 and I try to update data, but it won't save, and it really strange.

**Controller**

```php
private function _generatePaymentToken($kode)
{
    $this->initPaymentGateway();
    $pnd = new Pendaftar;
    $pnd = $pnd::where('nohp', $kode)->get();
    if ($pnd->count()) {
        $customerDetails = [
            'first_name' => $pnd[0]->nama,
            'last_name' => $pnd[0]->nama,
            'email' => $pnd[0]->email,
            'phone' => $pnd[0]->nohp,
        ];

        $params = [
            'transaction_details' => [
                'order_id' => $pnd[0]->kode_transaksi,
                'gross_amount' => 5000,
            ],
            'customer_details' => $customerDetails,
            'expiry' => [
                'start_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s T'),
                'unit' => setting('site.unit_expire'),
                'duration' => setting('site.time_expired'),
            ],
        ];

        $snap = \Midtrans\Snap::createTransaction($params);

        $pendaftar = Pendaftar::find($pnd[0]->id);

        $pendaftar->token = $snap->token;
        $pendaftar->save;

        // dd($pendaftar->save);
        return $snap;

    } else {
        return view('404');
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Pendaftar extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pendaftar';
    protected $primary_key = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['nama, email, nohp,orangtuawali, alamat, tempat_tanggal_lahir,asal_sekolah, satutahun_regular, satutahun_hybrid,duatahun, sarjana_plus, ihcp, ecp, periode_pendaftaran, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at, kode_refrensi, kode_transaksi,kampus,token'];
}
```

The `$pendaftar->save` before return is not working

I try to `dd($pendaftar->save)` it give me `null`

and if I `dd($pendaftar)` it gives me this

```
App\Pendaftar {#1840
  #table: "pendaftar"
  #primary_key: "id"
  #fillable: array:1 [
    0 => "nama, email, nohp,orangtuawali, alamat, tempat_tanggal_lahir,asal_sekolah, satutahun_regular, satutahun_hybrid,duatahun, sarjana_plus, ihcp, ecp, periode_pendaftaran, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at, kode_refrensi, kode_transaksi,kampus,token"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:22 [
    "id" => "6"
    "nama" => "Putu Elanda"
    "email" => "biruxxx@mail.com"
    "nohp" => "0878xxx"
    "orangtuawali" => "Nyoman Elendiana"
    "alamat" => "Singaraja"
    "tempat_tanggal_lahir" => "Singaraja / 10 Januari 1996"
    "asal_sekolah" => "SMK N 3 Singaraja"
    "satutahun_regular" => null
    "satutahun_hybrid" => null
    "duatahun" => null
    "sarjana_plus" => null
    "ihcp" => "Profesi 2 Tahun "
    "ecp" => "Food Entrepreneurship and Culinary Art"
    "periode_pendaftaran" => "Januari"
    "created_at" => "2020-12-20 14:15:03"
    "updated_at" => "2020-12-20 14:15:03"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "kode_refrensi" => "BHT08"
    "kode_transaksi" => "2012POSA"
    "kampus" => null
    "token" => "9067715d-aa54-4b10-a457-5445f06df3c4"
  ]
  #original: array:22 [
    "id" => "6"
    "nama" => "Putu Elanda"
    "email" => "biruxxx@mail.com"
    "nohp" => "0878xxx"
    "orangtuawali" => "Nyoman Elendiana"
    "alamat" => "Singaraja"
    "tempat_tanggal_lahir" => "Singaraja / 10 Januari 1996"
    "asal_sekolah" => "SMK N 3 Singaraja"
    "satutahun_regular" => null
    "satutahun_hybrid" => null
    "duatahun" => null
    "sarjana_plus" => null
    "ihcp" => "Profesi 2 Tahun "
    "ecp" => "Food Entrepreneurship and Culinary Art"
    "periode_pendaftaran" => "Januari"
    "created_at" => "2020-12-20 14:15:03"
    "updated_at" => "2020-12-20 14:15:03"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "kode_refrensi" => "BHT08"
    "kode_transaksi" => "2012POSA"
    "kampus" => null
    "token" => ""
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

I don't really know what wrong with this, or maybe is there's something I miss?

Comment: this `$pendaftar->save;` save should be a function `$pendaftar->save();`

Comment: My gosh, I think I should go to sleep now. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your $fillable array is defined incorrectly - each column name should be an element of the array - wrapped in quotes. Otherwise none of the fields would be allowed for mass assignment.

Which means even if the update or save methods will not throw error - data won't be saved to database for these columns.

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Pendaftar extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pendaftar';
    protected $primary_key = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'nama',
        'email',
        'nohp',
        'orangtuawali',
        'alamat',
        'tempat_tanggal_lahir',
        'asal_sekolah',
        'satutahun_regular',
        'satutahun_hybrid',
        'duatahun', 
        'sarjana_plus',
        'ihcp',
        'ecp',
        'periode_pendaftaran',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
        'kode_refrensi',
        'kode_transaksi',
        'kampus,token'
    ];
}
```

And as @bhucho has pointed out `save()` is a method not property, so statement should be

```php
$pendaftar->save();
```